# upload a file and use summarytools in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a code as folows and my objective is to create an interactive data visialissation shinyapp but I can not print out the summarytool table properly which can be found in  [image: here]. Any help will be appriciated and many thanks in advance.

```
`## Only run examples in interactive R sessions
if (interactive()) {
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                  accept = c(
                    "text/csv",
                    "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                    ".csv")
        ),
        tags$hr(),
        checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE)
      ),
 
       mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel( "tab1",tableOutput("contents")),
          tabPanel("dfSummary Output", htmlOutput("profileSummary")))
      )
    )
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output) {
    output$contents <- renderTable({
      # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
      # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
      # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
      # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
      # be found.
      inFile <- input$file1
      
      if (is.null(inFile))
        return(NULL)
      
      read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
    })
    
    output$profileSummary <- renderTable({
      
      inFile <- input$file1
      
      if (is.null(inFile))
        return(NULL)
     
      SumProfile <-  summarytools::view(dfSummary(inFile$datapath))
      return(SumProfile)
    })
    
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}`
```

Comment: It is viewable in RStudio's viewer if you use renderUI instead of renderTable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To view the html file, not just the location of the html file, you could save it in a tmp file and display it with `includeHTML()`.  Try this

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                accept = c(
                  "text/csv",
                  "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                  ".csv")
      ),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE)
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel( "tab1",tableOutput("contents")),
        tabPanel("dfSummary Output", htmlOutput("inc") 
                 ))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  dat <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    
    read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
  })
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    req(dat())
    dat()
  })
  
  output$profileSummary <- renderUI({
    
    req(dat())
    
    SumProfile <-   summarytools::view(summarytools::dfSummary(dat(), style="grid", method = "render"),
                                       omit.headings = TRUE,
                                       bootstrap.css = FALSE,
                                       escape.pipe = TRUE,
                                       file = "./tmp.html"
                                       )
    SumProfile
  })
  
  getPage<-function() {
    return(includeHTML("./tmp.html"))
  }
  output$inc<-renderUI({
    req(dat())
    getPage()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: Neat! :) Two little things: 1) since the graphs are a bit too large, adding `graph.magnif = .75` (more or less) would help. 2) I don't think `escape.pipe = TRUE` has any effect here, correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Agree - please change the options as necessary.  I was just trying to show that you can save and display.  Options should be adjusted as desired.

Comment: @DominicComtois, summarytools is a great package.  I had not used it before.

Answer (score 1):

The below code should solve the problem. I changed mainly two things:

1. I replaced `renderTable` with `renderUI`
2. I added the argument `method = "render"` to the `summarytools::dfSummary` function

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                accept = c(
                  "text/csv",
                  "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                  ".csv")
      ),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE)
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel( "tab1",tableOutput("contents")),
        tabPanel("dfSummary Output", htmlOutput("profileSummary")))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
    # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
    # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
    # be found.
    inFile <- input$file1
    
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    
    read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
  })
  
  output$profileSummary <- renderUI({
    
    inFile <- input$file1
    
    if (is.null(inFile)) {
      return(NULL)
    } else {
      summarytools::view(summarytools::dfSummary(inFile$datapath), method = "render")
    }
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Here's a modified version that works: https://gist.github.com/dcomtois/3ceb928b78b9840d1ba2b15660a9ae52